# How to initialize `const char **` from `char **`?

Tags: c++, string, constants, argv, clang++

I want to write the function, that will accept the standard `argv` from `main()` and my own const strings, like: `const char* strings[] = {"a", "b", "c", nullptr};`

Trying the following with clang++ 3.4:

```
void f(int argc, const char* argv[]) { ... }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  f(argc, argv);
  return 0;
}
```

And get error: `no known conversion from 'char **' to 'const char **'`

What am I doing wrong? May I just apply `const_cast`?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html

Comment: @JoeZ I would upvote your link twice because of comment _"it's illegal and immoral to convert..."_ LOL LOL LOL

Comment: Thanks, it works, I should delete the question...or not delete - for history. It's quite hard to google something with double `*`.

Comment: @abyss.7 No, you shouldn't. StackOverflow is here to keep knowledge around, while deleting the question would cause it to be lost.

Comment: @Adriano Not sure what the “LOL” refers to. “illegal” and “immoral” are well-defined terms in the context of the C++ FAQ. They’re not hyperbole.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't know, still searching for their explanation in FAQ...

Comment: @JoeZ Thanks for this, I wasn't aware.  I modified my answer to make note of this.

Comment: @Adriano Here you go: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html – As for legality: this is defined in the C++ standard. Legal C++ code is code which conforms to the standard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph of course for _legal_, what makes me laugh is "immoral"!